# IIS: this webpage has a redirect loop

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, iis, windows-server-2012-r2

I have developed a very simple Asp.Net MVC app (.Net 4.5.1) and I have bought a server 2012 R2 on which I have installed IIS and tried to deploy my app. The app gets deployed and it loads it's first page (the login page) fine, however, after I try to enter the username and password and actually log in, I get this error (if I use Chrome by the way. In case I use IE I just get a generic non-informative error):

"this webpage has a redirect loop".

Needless to say, the app runs perfectly fine in my own computer and using Visual Studio 2013. I am putting my web.config file here in case it helps:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301880
  -->
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>

  </connectionStrings>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <authentication mode="None" />
    <compilation targetFramework="4.5.1" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.1" />
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules>
      <remove name="FormsAuthentication" />
    </modules>
  <handlers>
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
      <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
      <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
    </handlers></system.webServer>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-5.2.2.0" newVersion="5.2.2.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Optimization" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.1.0.0" newVersion="1.1.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.5.2.14234" newVersion="1.5.2.14234" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

Fyi I have taken the connection string out, but rest assured it is fine. Because in the first page of the app, when I try to create a new user and click submit, it does create that user in the database and then gives me the error in the browser.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Oh and by the way, it is definitely not a client side Chrome issue.

Comment: i believe this is not related to your configuration. look for logical errors in  authentication/authorization management. Some thing like "login page needs authorization" might be the issue. Use browser console or tools like fiddler to identify which urls are involved in the loop, and try resolving the issue

Comment: Well, I haven't touched the Visual Studio default Authentication functions. Do you still think those default, scaffold-ed functions can be wrong? If yes, what do I do?

Comment: @behroozdalvandi: use Fiddler or any other http debugger to find the culprit resource.

Comment: Show your code - the configuration code for authentication and your logon controller / action.

Comment: Here is a link to my AccountController.cs file:  https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bxo0t7PWWB52R0hOeVRnZHVGWHc/view?usp=sharing

Thanks in advance!

Comment: @BrendanGreen come back! :D please!

Comment: here is the details of the error: The webpage at http://localhost/takeoutweb/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2Ftakeoutweb%2FAccount%2FLogin%3FReturnUrl%3D%252Ftakeoutweb%252FAccount%252FLogin%253FReturnUrl%253D%25252Ftakeoutweb%25252FAccount%25252FLogin%25253FReturnUrl%25253D%2525252Ftakeoutweb%2525252FAccount%2525252FLogin%2525253FReturnUrl%2525253D%252525252Ftakeoutweb%has resulted in too many redirects. Clearing your cookies for this site or allowing third-party cookies may fix the problem. If not, it is possibly a server configuration issue and not a problem with your computer

Comment: As a test, after the login redirect to a page that does not require authorization (like the home page). It could be possible that you are redirected to a page that requires authorization and it is not set up right so it redirects you back to the login page repeatedly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I just want to say how I resolved the issue, maybe it will be a help to someone. Before that, I must say I searched the whole freaking internet and this issue is one of those that happens a millions times, but each time due to a different reason!
Mine was this: simply change this part of web config:

```
AuthenticationMode="None"
```

To

```
AuthenticationMode="Forms"
```

Yes... That took 3 weeks of my time...